# Display Redis values in HTML using Node.JS and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, redis

I am working on a Big Data project which is constantly pushing real-time data to a Redis database. Right now I have keys stored with counts that are increasing over time. I want to:

- Display these counts as they are updating through a web page
- Use node.js to query values from Redis
- Use AngularJS to query node.js to display the values.

I can run the following node.js app in terminal to print out the key values

## NodeApp.js

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.on('connect', runSample);

function runSample() {

    var myTimer = setInterval(function() {

        console.log('=============================');
        console.log('            Totals           ');
        console.log('=============================');

        client.get('launch', function (err, reply) {
            if(reply) {
                console.log('launch: ' + reply.toString());
            }
        });
        client.get('resume', function (err, reply) {
            if(reply) {
                console.log('resume: ' + reply.toString());
            }
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="APP">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="EventTypeController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="theme.css">
        <title>Redis Data</title>
    </head>
    <div id="main" ng-controller="EventTypeController" ng-init="init()">

        <h1>Event Types</h1>
        <div class="centerwrapper">

            <div class="box">

                <p class="eventCount">{{launch}}</p>
                <p class="eventName">Launch</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box">

                <p class="eventCount">{{resume}}</p>
                <p class="eventName">Resume</p>
            </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

## EventTypeController.js

```
angular.module('APP', [])
  .controller('EventTypeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.launch = 0;
    $scope.resume = 0;

    $scope.init = function() {
        // run nodeapp.js file
        // set $scope.launch to redis key value
        // repeat for $scope.resume
        // continue to read over time interval
    };
}]);
```

How can I get the value from reply.toString() in an HTML file to continually update the text of a < p>?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Redis [pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) combined with [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup a two-way communication system to accomplish this. Since you are using NodeJS, you could install an HTTP server of your choice to serve your content on the server side. On the client side, you could query with Angular's $http service and use their $interval function to make repeated calls. As Explosion Pills stated, if you're expecting a high frequency of read/writes it would be better to move to websockets.

Here's a very basic server-side example using [express](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html):

```
var redis = require('redis');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// Add your redis setup here
var client = redis.createClient();

app.get('/query', function(req, res){
    // Query your redis dataset here
    client.get('data', function(err, reply) {
       // Handle errors if they occur
       if(err) res.status(500).end();
       // You could send a string
       res.send(reply.toString());
       // or json
       // res.json({ data: reply.toString() });
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Since you are using AngularJS, you could use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service to pull data on demand at a set interval using [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Here's a basic example going off Angular's $interval example:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', function($scope, $http, $interval) {

    $scope.value = '';
    var query;

    $scope.init = function() {
        // Check if we already have an active interval in the scope
        if(angular.isDefined(query)) 
            return;

        // Setup query interval
        query = $interval(function() {
            // Call the endpoint where you will retrieve data from
            $http.get('/query')
            .success(function(data) {
                // Handle data, you could 
                // update one or both values
                $scope.value = data;
            })
            .error(function(err) {
                // Handle errors
            });
        }, 100); // Execute every 100 milliseconds
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() { 
        if(angular.isDefined(query)) {
            $interval.cancel(query);
            query = undefined;
        }
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        // Make sure that the interval is destroyed too
        $scope.cancel();
    });
}]);
```

Anyway, this is just to give you an idea of one way to go about your issue. Good luck.

Comment: I ended up using socket.io  for the implementation in a similar way as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Angular runs on the client and node runs on the server, so you need a way to communicate between the two.  Assuming a fairly low level of reading and writing you can stick with the [`$http` service](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ng/service/%24http) or its variants.  This would also require using an [HTTP server](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) on the server side to write the value to a response rather than just using `console.log`.  If you expect high frequency of reads and writes you may do well to use [web sockets](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io).